# Como mostrar somente a data sem a hora com Date()

Tags: javascript

Estou montando uma data para ser exibida em um input, essa será a data de hoje menos um dia, mas preciso somente da data e está me mostrando Data e Hora, como posso fazer?

O que tenho até agora é isso:

```
var Hoje = new Date();
Hoje.setDate(Hoje.getDate() - 1);
var Today = Hoje.toLocaleString();
var Today = Today.replace(new RegExp("/", 'g'),"-" );
editors['DataIndice'].setValue(Today);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var Hoje = new Date();
Hoje.setDate(Hoje.getDate() - 1);
//string apenas de data em um formato determinado pelo browser
var Today = Hoje.toDateString();
// string apenas de data no formato localizado do seu sistema
var Today2 = Hoje.toLocaleDateString();

var dataTracinho = Today2.replace(new RegExp("/","g"), "-"); 

console.log (Today);
console.log (Today2);
console.log (dataTracinho);
```

suporte:

Fiz teste com os 6 principais navegadores, Chome, IE, Edge Firefox, Opera

[image: 5principais]

e Safari

[image: safari]

> Para todos os navegadores pode-se usar  [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)
>   veja um clicando  [**aqui**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/date3.htm)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="date.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
   var d1 = Date.parse('today');;
   document.write(d1.toString('dd-MM-yyyy'));
</script>
```

Comment: Cara, bacana! +1... Só queria saber se tem suporte a todos navegadores. Seria interessante pôr essa informação.

Answer (score 6):

Eu faria assim:

```js
 var data = new Date().toLocaleString().substr(0, 10)

 console.log(data)
```

Mas é importante relatar que, quando usei isso, não funcionou muito bem no Internet Explorer (como era de se esperar).

Em todo caso, recomendo sempre usar a biblioteca [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)

Exemplo:

```js
var data = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');



console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Para diminuir um dia no `moment`, você pode usar o método `add`

```js
var date = moment().add(-1, 'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY');


console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -4):

```js
const dataDeHoje = new Date();

const hora = dataDeHoje.toLocaleString([], {
  hour: "2-digit",
  minute: "2-digit"
});

//Receba o resultado das horas impresso no console
console.log(hora)
```

Comment: Leia a pergunta novamente e veja que o autor da pergunta quer *a data de hoje menos um dia, mas quer exibir somente da data sem exibir horários*.